# How to read key from aws instance and add into my mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

lets take my query is

```
Insert into table1 values (AES_ENCRYPT('mypassword', some_secure_key));
```

I am storing some_secure_key in key management service in aws . I want to fetch and use this key in my query .

I am running this query from local system.

system detail
mysql_version :- 5.7.23
OS:- linux

Comment: Please make your question more specific.  You are assuming that readers of your question are familiar with your setup.  That are probably not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AES_DECRYPT` for decryption:

```
SELECT description, AES_DECRYPT(description,some_secure_key) 
FROM table1 ;
```